# Research Sources for $SL(2,R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, topological-groups

Can anyone guide me to a good site for the special linear group $SL(2,R)$, especially one that goes deep into its subgroup and normal subgroup? Book recommendations would be great too.

Comment: Probably not really what you're looking for, but it came to mind because I read it recently: http://www.springerlink.com/content/k7585171n6341825/fulltext.pdf
It's only really concerened with representation theory in order to do some harmonic analysis, but hopefully you'll find something of interest there.

Comment: Google it. A good algebra books is better though.

Comment: Actually, book recommendations would be great, also. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, @Peter, I think I'd enjoy this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read [$SL_2(R)$](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387961984) by Serge Lang. The title is exactly the topic you are looking for!

Comment: Who knew? (I guess you did!)